# import janitor as jn TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pyjanitor

after sucessfully downloading the module

```
 !pip install  pyjanitor # works successfully
```

```
import janitor as jn # which worked just fine in the past, but suddenly throwing the following TypeError
```

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
I am using google colab.
I also tried just import janitor instead of import janitor as jn,  that also didn't work
any help to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I think that's the package's error.

Another person also reported the error that he couldn't import the package.

> https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/issues/1201

According to [the GitHub issue page](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/issues/1200#issuecomment-1321504519), They plan to fix it. the current version is 0.24.0

> his issue will be fixed at pyjanitor 0.24.1

## There are several ways to fix it.

**Until the fix is released, use the previous package.**

To remove the current pyjanitor in jupyter

```
!pip uninstall pyjanitor --yes
```

To install the previous version of the package in jupyter.

```
!pip install pyjanitor==0.23.1
```

**OR if you are familiar with the library, you may fix the bug with [this comment](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/issues/1200#issuecomment-1321493007)**

```
!pip show pyjanitor
```

It shows a message like this.

```
Name: pyjanitor
Version: 0.24.0
Summary: Tools for cleaning pandas DataFrames
Home-page: https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor
Author: pyjanitor devs
Author-email: ericmajinglong@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: lazy-loader, multipledispatch, natsort, pandas-flavor, scipy
Required-by:
```

In my case, I have to go to **Location:** `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` and find a directory called `janitor`

Put a string `from __future__ import annotations` in these files.

```
janitor/utils.py
janitor/functions/conditional_join.py
janitor/functions/utils.py
```

**OR you can try `pyjanitor` on python 3.9+.**

Comment: fwiw i just submitted a Pull Request to fix that

Comment: I changed the way to uninstall the package in Jupiter. @onkaronkar4

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem (on January 2023) and installing previous version solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: again at the same issue now installing !pip install pyjanitor==0.23.1 works but import pyjanitor doesnt work and throws error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyjanitor'

Comment: ok this issue was resolved I used import janitor instead of import pyjanitor and it woks. little confusing the the package name is pyjanitor and when import we need to use janitor